# EVRC NW codec not decode audio from raw file

Tags: audio, decoding, codec, cdma

I am working on EVRCNW codec to integrate with our existing product, for that purpose i have downloaded the Enhanced Variable Rate Codec ([[http://www.3gpp2.org/Public_html/Specs/C.R0014-D_v1.0_EVRC-D_SoftwareDistribution_100125.zip]](http://www.3gpp2.org/Public_html/Specs/C.R0014-D_v1.0_EVRC-D_SoftwareDistribution_100125.zip)) ‘C.R0014-D v1.0’  version from 3gpp2 site and after compilation and reading "ReadMe" File.

I am fetching initial raw file from  pcap using wireshark.
I have given raw file with specificed format to encoder after that intermediate file(.pkt file) to decoder. Which generate another raw file.That Raw file i have given to SOX or Audacity software to generate wav file.

But in the wave file i am only getting noise nothing else.

Is there anything else need to do to fetch audio from it?
If any sample pcap file with contain EVRC NW as RTP will be very helpful.I searched over internet but not didn't find any.

Thanks in advance.